# Getting an error while installing SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019

I was trying the installation of SQL Server 2019 in my machine.
I faced one issue in the screen shot.

[image: Error image]

**Update:**

I already added OLEDB Driver for Sql Server as below image.

[image: OLEDB]

Comment: Try installing this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/installing-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DJHemath already did but issue remain same.